# Can't change video subtitles codec using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've got a mkv file with somes streams embedded:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x300, SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 48003.07 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1(tr): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:2(fr): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x300
```

When playing on my PC, I can see subtitles. When playing it from my old DVD/DIVX player, I cannot see the subtitles (other mkv/avi work fine).

So I wanted to change the subtitle encoding, to see if another one could work with my DVD player.

ffmpeg -encoders reports:

```
 S..... ssa                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle (codec ass)
 S..... ass                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle
 S..... dvbsub               DVB subtitles (codec dvb_subtitle)
 S..... dvdsub               DVD subtitles (codec dvd_subtitle)
 S..... mov_text             3GPP Timed Text subtitle
 S..... srt                  SubRip subtitle (codec subrip)
 S..... subrip               SubRip subtitle
 S..... text                 Raw text subtitle
 S..... webvtt               WebVTT subtitle
 S..... xsub                 DivX subtitles (XSUB)
```

So I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -scodec "codec" converted.mkv
```

with various versions of "codec". None of them will work (except the original `dvdsub`...):

xsub reports:

```
[matroska @ 0x24558c0] Subtitle codec 94211 is not supported.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Function not implemented
[matroska @ 0x24558c0] Subtitle codec 94211 is not supported.
Error writing trailer of mustang_converted.mkv: Function not implementedframe=  244 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:10.01 bitrate=   1.0kbits/s speed=1.23e+03x    
video:321kB audio:235kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

ssa or ass reports:

```
[ssa @ 0x262e000] Only SUBTITLE_ASS type supported.
Subtitle encoding failed
```

others reports:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

What am I doing wrong? Are some subtitles codec incompatible with the current video or audio codec? Should I change those instead of copying?

Alternatively, is there an option to merge subtitle within the video images stream for good (and then have only two output streams: audio and video but preserve subtitles display)?

Note: Answer using another tool than ffmpeg are acceptable, if working under Linux (mint).

Comment: Note to new readers of this question: This isn't on-topic here on Stack Overflow. See  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your subtitles are image-based and need to be converted to a text-based format like SRT. Use [Subtitle Edit](http://www.videohelp.com/software/Subtitle-Edit) or similar tool to import the subs from MKV. This will do OCR processing of the subs. Once done, save as SRT or any common text-based subtitle format.

Then run your ffmpeg command with scodec of your choice.

---

Alternatively, if you want to burn in the subtitles, you can try one of these methods

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=input.mkv -acodec copy -sn converted.mkv
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:2]overlay" -acodec copy -sn converted.mkv
```

Comment: Can't use Subtitle Edit under Linux. Your first ffmpeg command failed with error `Only text based subtitles are currently supported`, but the second worked (video quality was decreased, file output is 3 times smaller....but with subtitles working!!!). Thanks

Comment: You can insert `-crf 20` to increase video quality.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: By the way, could you explain in your post what means this magic 'filter_complex' parameter?

Comment: I am writing a script for automated mkv to mp4 conversion to be used by Plex Media Server in Ubuntu. I am having this problem. I want ffmpeg to ignore the error, and just discard the substitles stream if a problem like this arises. How?

Comment: You would use two commands: a) `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:s sub.mp4 ` b) Check if sub.mp4 exists and is non-zero size (alternatively, check if exit code of cmd a is successful). If no, `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -sn out.mp4`. If yes, `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: A more complete example—this works with ffmpeg 4.4.4 to burn in subtitle track #4, along with audio track #2, with pretty good image quality (honestly you might want to increase `crf` to reduce recoding quality if your source material is less than ~5GB for 1 hour, otherwise filesize bloat could be unnecessary): `ffmpeg -i film.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:s:4]overlay" -c:a copy -map 0:a:2 -sn -crf 15 -strict -2 film-sub.mp4`. Then you can add external SRT subtitles in your player (such as VLC) and watch with two subs simultaneously (which you might want when, e.g., learning a new language).