# Extract pgssub subtitles from mkv to txt (srt)

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, mkv, srt

How to correctly extract pgssub subtitles to txt file?

I have this target input stream:

> Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080 (default)

I want save this subtitles like srt into txt file:

```
$ ffmpeg -i inp.mkv -map 0:2 eng.srt
```

ffmpeg says:

```
blah blah blah...
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> subrip (srt))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

How to correctly extract this subtitles?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327919/5726027

Comment: @aergistal, LordNeckbeard this question not about ffmpeg. This question about pgssub subtitles and only try with ffmpeg. Yes. Mulvya answer is useful, but this questions is different.