# ffmpeg: convert subtitles from "hdmv_pgs_subtitle" to "mov_text" (needed in MP4)

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to convert subtitles from "hdmv_pgs_subtitle" to "mov_text" (needed in MP4).

I try:

```
ffmpeg.exe i "%%F" c copy -scodec mov_text "test.mp4"
```

but I get:
`Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2` - maybe incorrect parameters
such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Stream properties:

```
Duration: 00:01:48.14, start: 4199.920000, bitrate: 12394 kb/s
Program 1
Stream #0:0[0x1011], 169, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1100], 102, 1/90000: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x1200], 35, 1/90000: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
```

Comment: Same answer applies as at https://stackoverflow.com/q/36326790/5726027